# Like - unlike functionality without user login in website

Tags: laravel, facebook-like

I want to implement like and unlike functionality with likes count in website like instagram. But the website has no user login. It is open to all. So how can I implement this functionality? Please also provide references with your answer.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, this is not a website which will grant any of your desires, try it out first surf the net, f you get struck in implementation then only ask for help

Comment: read [how to ask on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question is not specific at all. SO is for helping with coding problems not for tutorials when you start from scratch.